# want to precompile jsp and map the resulting .class file in the web.xml

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

I compiled jsp using `java weblogic.jspc . index.jsp` it gave me a directory and .class file. now i wants to map this .class file in the web.xml. my problem is that i dont have the 
servlet name in which jsp is converted during its life cycle.

i know how to map the servlet in the web.xml but in case of jsp i have the .class file but dont have the servlet class. please help me how can i do this task?

Answer (score 1):

The servlet name doesn't matter. You can choose whatever servlet name you want. It's merely used to locate the relationships between `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` declarations inside `web.xml`. Just put the class file (complete with the directory structure!) in `/WEB-INF/classes` the usual way and map it as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>indexJsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>some.weblogic.specific.packagename.GeneratedClassNameOfIndexJsp</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>indexJsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `indexJsp` servlet name is completely free to your choice. What matters is that the `<servlet-class>` points the right FQN of the generated class file and the `<url-pattern>` specifies the URL on which you'd like to invoke this.

Comment: i have my _index.class file in jsp_servlet directory. Now i will put my jsp_servlet directory in the WEB-INF/classes directory then i will write "some.weblogic.jsp_servlet._index" between my servlet-class tag. Am I correct or not?

Comment: No, the "some.weblogic" part is just an example, because I have no idea what FQN it generates. But you said, it generates just one folder `jsp_servlet` with therein already the class file? If so, then the FQN is `jsp_servlet._index`.